# Bash: on the escapping of the variables within printf

Tags: bash, variables, printf

I have a script in bash which print some file with another script which do again the same job (the first script print another executable script which again produce the third one):

```
#!/bin/bash
# it is a first script which I have
home=$(pwd)
output=${home}/output

printf "#!/bin/bash
# it is a second script which will be printed upon execution of the first script
k=2 # number of resubmission
i=32 # cpu to use
time="1:30:00"
HOME=\$(pwd)
for sim in \${HOME}/* ; do
  cd \${sim}
  printf \"#!/bin/csh
  # it is a third script which will be printed only upon execution of the second script
set cnt    = \${k}
set cntmax = 10

while ( \${cnt} <= \${cntmax} )
do something
done" > \${sim}/the_inside_script.sh
cd -
done" > ${output}/the_outside_script.sh
```

Here a question regarding the third (internal) script file:

```
printf \"#!/bin/csh

set cnt    = \${k}
set cntmax = 10

while ( \${cnt} <= \${cntmax} ) # I need always escape these variables
do something
done"
```

Because it will be printed by another script which will be printed by the first one, I need to escape each variable within the 3rd one - two times - so in the the_inside_script.sh the variables \${cnt} and \${cntmax} should be still escaped (it does not work now) and the ${k} should not be escaped (it is correct now). An expected output of the internal script should be with all open variables:

```
#!/bin/csh
# it is a third script which will be printed only upon execution of the second script
set cnt    = 2
set cntmax = 10

while ( ${cnt} <= ${cntmax} ) # here the variables are present explicitly
do something
done
```

In the current version the ${cnt} and ${cntmax} are not expected, thus it will be lost.

```
#!/bin/csh
# it is a current version of the third script which will be printed only upon execution of the second script
set cnt    = 2
set cntmax = 10

while (  <=  ) # here the variables are present explicitly
do something
done
```

How to escape \${cnt} and \${cntmax} properly at the second time of printf?

I thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you generating scripts like this? You can probably do what you want another way. Dynamic script creation is an anti-pattern.

Comment: You don't want to interpolate any variables, right?

Comment: Don't interpolate values into the script; call the script with arguments.

Comment: it is just a scripts for computational science jobs - its initially replicate some folder putting some sh script inside and outside for some control of the jobs on server. I really dont know another ways to do it because not very in computational and programming :-) so the question I think yes I need to isolate \${cnt} and \${cntmax} variables within the inner script ... I provide an example of expected output in the firtst message

Comment: This is followup to a prior question, no? Why are you using `printf` for the whole script, vs only the part where you need to safely substitute values?

Comment: Which is to say: Don't (ever!) substitute values into a printf format string at all. The whole reason format strings **exist** is to provide a way to specify where to substitute values. Use those placeholders, and pass dynamic values out-of-band, if and when `printf` is the right tool for the job (which it almost certainly isn't here).

Comment: So I need to call printf for each string and step-by-step add it to the new script? Seems to routine. Are there alternative solutions? would be greate to see an example

Comment: Heh. Actually, not a followup, but you're independently asking a question about how to perform the exact same task as someone else asked yesterday (with slightly different preconceptions about intended approach).

Comment: Follow the link at the top of the question (to the other one of which it's flagged duplicative).

Comment: You should use quoted heredocs instead of that printf: `cat << 'END_BASH' > output.script` then put the script without having to escape variable references, then a line containing only `END_BASH`

Comment: @glennjackman, right -- that's the answer I gave the other person with this question yesterday, after using `printf` for the one variable they *did* want to inject.

Comment: that's too complex ;-( I dont understand that syntax. The example with printf seems to me logically clear - I just print the new file calling the script etc. Not possible to escape selected variables for unlimited time in printf via some specifial command? Thus I need that the variable always was like \${var}

Comment: @user3470313, you don't need to escape things if you don't put them in double quotes. `'$var'` doesn't need any escaping to be printed exactly with its original literal contents. Anyhow -- if you're having trouble understanding something (particular, something that people who are experts are telling you is a best-practice approach), instead of avoiding it, *ask about it*.

Comment: @user3470313, ...and your `printf` approach is not nearly so clear as you think it is. For instance, you're failing to escape the double quotes inside string, so they're actually ending and later resuming quoted context, not serving as literal parts of the document being built at all.

Comment: (and btw, when I urge you to "ask about it" -- doing so with a [mcve], the shortest possible code that showcases a given issue, will be far better received than posting a dense, complicated script with a bunch of additional/unrelated bugs).

Comment: I really don't know about efficacy of the bash coding. I just use it to produce some regular scripts for run my scientific jobs automatically and do something with data :-) sorry I am not a computational guy! so with printf is not possible to write 3 scripts one from another keeping the vars inside the last-one, isn't it?